# Extract text from log file based on a specific date and export to CSV in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, shell, datatable, export

I have a file containing logs for months and I want to store only the logs for a specific data into a csv file.

sample log data:

2022-06-21 09:06:09 15SS1B Equip = Z39 Text -0003254 Equipment has been added on-line

2022-07-21 09:06:09 15SS2B Equip = Z40 Text -0003254 Equipment has been added on-line

2022-08-21 09:06:09 15SS3B Equip = Z41 Text -0003254 Equipment has been added on-line

2022-09-21 09:06:09 15SS4B Equip = Z42 Text -0003254 Equipment has been added on-line

I get the result with the following columns:  IgnoreCase, LineNumber, Line, Filename, Path, Pattern, Context, Matches.
I'm only interested in the result of Line column only.

Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

This is my code:

```
$data = Get-Content '\log.log' | Select-String -Pattern "2022-08-21" | Export-CSV -Path '\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

my request is to get that content and export them into new table like:

`Date         Time        Number Type`

`2022-06-21   09:06:09    15SS1B Equip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regular expression on this in order to parse out the wanted parts and output these as properties of objects:

```
$dateToSearch = '2022-08-21' 
$regex = "^(?<date>$dateToSearch)\s+(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<number>[a-z\d]+)\s+(?<type>\w+)\s+=\.*"

Get-Content -Path '\log.log' | Where-Object { $_ -match $regex } | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {$matches['date']}},
                  @{Name = 'Time'; Expression = {$matches['time']}},
                  @{Name = 'Number'; Expression = {$matches['number']}},
                  @{Name = 'Type'; Expression = {$matches['type']}} |
    Export-CSV -Path '\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Or use a loop instead of calculated properties:

```
$dateToSearch = '2022-08-21' 
$regex = "^(?<date>$dateToSearch)\s+(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<number>[a-z\d]+)\s+(?<type>\w+)\s+=\.*"

Get-Content -Path '\log.log' | Where-Object { $_ -match $regex } | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Date   = $matches['date']
        Time   = $matches['time']
        Number = $matches['number']
        Type   = $matches['type']
    }
} | Export-CSV -Path '\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result

```
Date       Time     Number Type 
----       ----     ------ ---- 
2022-08-21 09:06:09 15SS3B Equip
```

Comment: I am so behind in learning regex :(  Once again you taught me the importance of using regex. Thank You!

Comment: @AshenOne Thanks for the nice feedback. Being new to SO, may I point you to the [tour] where amongst other interesting stuff you can read how to mark a question 'done'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this, I did it for one line, the same can be used for multiple lines also.

```
$line = "2022-06-21 09:06:09 15SS1B Equip = Z39 Text -0003254 Equipment has been added on-line"
$data = $line.Split("=")[0]
$result = $data.Split(" ") # A Space in between quotes
[pscustomObject]@{
   Date = $result[0]
   Time = $result[1]
   Number = $result[2]
   Type = $result[3]
}
```